# MySql - Join not giving expected result

Tags: mysql, join

trying to run below query, expecting to find a match. Since my two sub-queries are same, i am expecting to find a match, which is not happening here.

```
select TAB_1.RUL_IDD, TAB_2.RUL_IDD
FROM
(   select aaa.RUL_ID RUL_IDD from TEST_1 aaa 
    inner join 
    (
    select dt,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    from (
        select distinct DATE(BTCH_RUN_DTTM) dt
        FROM      TEST_1 
        where       ALRT_FLG_IND = 'Y' 
                    and PASS_IND = 'N' 
                    and SCH_RUN_IND = 'Y'
        order by DATE(BTCH_RUN_DTTM) desc
         ) p,
        (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    order by dt desc
    ) zz 
    where DATE(aaa.BTCH_RUN_DTTM) = zz.dt
    and zz.rank=1
    and aaa.ALRT_FLG_IND = 'Y' 
    and aaa.PASS_IND = 'N' 
    and aaa.SCH_RUN_IND = 'Y'
) TAB_1
left outer JOIN 
(
    select bbb.RUL_ID as RUL_IDD from TEST_1 bbb 
    inner join 
    (
    select dt,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    from (
        select distinct DATE(BTCH_RUN_DTTM) dt
        FROM      TEST_1 
        where       ALRT_FLG_IND = 'Y' 
                    and PASS_IND = 'N' 
                    and SCH_RUN_IND = 'Y'
        order by DATE(BTCH_RUN_DTTM) desc
        ) p,
        (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    order by dt desc
    ) zzz 
    on DATE(bbb.BTCH_RUN_DTTM) = zzz.dt
    and zzz.rank=1
    and bbb.ALRT_FLG_IND = 'Y' 
    and bbb.PASS_IND = 'N' 
    and bbb.SCH_RUN_IND = 'Y'
)  TAB_2
on TAB_2.RUL_IDD = TAB_1.RUL_IDD;
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5wKU.jpg)

Not getting why its not giving the expected result. TAB_2.RUL_IDD should also have same value as TAB_1.RUL_IDD. Can experts help me over here?

Comment: curious, try renaming curRank in your 2nd subquery to curRank2 and see if you get what you want

Comment: yeah...it worked!! so it was initialization issue. Thanks Tin!!!